# CMD: '■m' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I am trying to get a batch file to work. Whenever I attempt to run a .bat the command line returns '■m' is not recognized... error, where "m" is the first letter of the file. For example:

`md c:\testsource
md c:\testbackup`

Returns

C:>"C:\Users\Michael\Dropbox\Documents\Research\Media\Method Guide\Program\test
.bat"

C:>■m
'■m' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Things I have tried:

1. Changing Path variables, rebooting, etc.
2. Changing file directory (i.e. run from C:)
3. Running example files from web (like above) to check for syntax errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What text editor are you writing this in? It seems like your text editor may save the file as UTF-16 encoded text, which `cmd.exe` can't handle. Try setting the "coding"/"file encoding" to "ANSI" when saving the file.

This results in the first byte being a byte-order-mark (telling other editors how to process the file), and `cmd.exe` can't deal with this.

Comment: That was the problem. I was editing in Notepad. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the approved answer I would add the case where is a PowerShell command the one that creates the file... PowerShell comes by default with the UTF-16 encoding.

To solve your problem then, force the file encoding lie this: `| out-file foo.txt -encoding utf8`

[Answer based on this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8).

Comment: thx! i ended up using `-encoding ascii` as even `-encoding utf8` left me with a bat file that would not execute.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 I had the same issue. 
Changing the character set to UTF-8 made it worse. 
It worked correctly when I selected Encoding as UTF-8-NO BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed encoding from

`UTF-16`

to

`UTF-8`