# IDLE can not open the .py file and it hints that "The file's encoding is invalid for Python 3.x."

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scrapy

I used the command `scrapy startproject tutorial` in `cmd`, and it creates some files, but these files can not be opened by IDLE. It hints that:

```
The file's encoding is invalid for Python 3.x.
IDLE will convert it to UTF-8.
What's the current encoding of the file?
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What's the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I use the Windows 7 operating system

Comment: In a `cmd` window, run `chcp` without arguments.

Comment: The encoding is 936,but when I input this,it can not work,and it hints 'failed to decode'

Comment: Maybe you can try running the scrapy command in a different shell that uses utf-8 instead of cp936? See here for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have not manually edited the contents of the ofending files before opening them with IDLE, the reason is probably a bug.

In that case, please [open a bug report about it](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues), preferrably detailing all the steps to follow to reproduce the issue, starting with the installation of Scrapy and ending with the issue you show on the screenshot.

In the meantime, you should be able to convert those files automatically from their current encoding to UTF-8 with any good plain text editor (e.g. Notepad++) or a specialized tool.