# how to get -verbose output to a text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get the verbose result to a log file in powershell, I m able to see the verbose line in shell but unable to get it into variable or log file

I have used `Tee-Object` and given the file path but it dont seems to be working

`Move-Item $source $_.File_Destination_Path -Force -Verbose | tee -Append -FilePath $Logfile`

Expected output in logfile- `"VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File...."`
But the result is blank, Please help me on this

Comment: Read `Get-Help about_redirection` or view [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @LotPings it does'nt says about taking verbose output in text file, I have already tried `Tee-Object` but it does'nt gives any output of verbose

Comment: Use `4>&1` to merge the verbose output stream (4) with the success output stream (1). `Get-Help about_redirection` clearly explains that.

Answer (score 3):

As comments have mentioned, you should check out [the `about_Redirection` msdn topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1).  In practice, it would look like:

```
Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $_.File_Destination_Path -Force -Verbose 4>&1 |
    Tee-Object -Append -FilePath $Logfile
```

Note the `VERBOSE:` bit is added by [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and you would need to append it yourself to have it visible in the output file.

Comment: able to get output on textfile, but the verbose output includes trail spaces between each char, Why it gives those space in file, but not their on screen

Comment: @fmsrv No idea what you're talking about, but it sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: @fmsrv refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8) it will help to solve your query based on encoding, can try `-encoding utf8`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have all the `Write-Verbose` messages in a text file is by using `Start-Transcript` as [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.4). This is especially useful for debugging PowerShell jobs.

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $params = @{
        Path      = 'C:\Temp\{0} transcript.txt' -f (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
        NoClobber = $true
    }
    Start-Transcript @params

    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

    # not in the text file
    Get-ChildItem 
    Write-Output 'this is output'

    # in the text file:
    Write-Verbose 'this is verbose' 
}

$job | Wait-Job
```