# Invoke-RestMethod in Azure Function not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am facing an issue with my Azure function (Powershell, timer trigger on Linux) which extracts values from Power Bi Service and pass them to a DevOps Pipeline when triggering it.
The triggering is done through `Invoke-RestMethod`.

The function works fine until it gets values which contain special german characters (Ü, Ö, Ä,...) then the body of the request is somehow broken and the function fails.

I think the problem is related to the encoding but the only possible solution I found is to add `charset=utf-8` to the header. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $secret")
    
$body = "{`"templateParameters`": {`"items`": `"$items`"}}"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/<repos>/<project>/_apis/pipelines/1/runs?api-version=7.0' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Items is a string of the form:
`[['filename','userx','Workspace','givendateTime']]`

when the `Workspace` has a `Ö` instead of 'o' an exception is raised:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: 
runParameters","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
+ ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Using Postman with the same parameters and values works fine.
Write-Host $body just before the Invoke-RestMethod is fine and the characters are correct.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried with unicode escape sequences in the json body? Eg. `"\u00d6l"` instead of `"Öl"` for example

Comment: Similar problem was resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449922/invoke-restmethod-utf8-characters

Comment: Hi Mathias,
Could you please explain a bit more your idea? I have no control on the values in the body. They are extracted from logs.

Comment: Thanks for the link Greg,
Unfortunately, it didn't work hier.