# MS Access insert UTF-8 with Powershell script

Tags: powershell, ms-access, oledb

I have a CSV file UTF-8 format with Spanish diacritics, if I load it from Access and select UTF-8 all is well. I want to automate my work so I made a Powershell script. Because the table is already created I can't load data with `SELECT *` but `INSERT INTO`. With `SELECT *` I can specify the UTF-8 Charset like `[text;HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=65001;]`. How can I do that with "INSERT INTO"?

My code so far (working but utf-8 characters are gibberish):

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
$connectstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\Mexico-test.accdb"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectstring)

$conn.Open()

$Voters = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\mexico.csv"

foreach ($Voter in $Voters)
{
    $curp = $Voter.curp
    $age = $Voter.age
    $forename = $Voter.forename
    $middlename = $Voter.middlename
    $surname = $Voter.surname
    $fatherSurname = $Voter.fatherSurname
    $motherSurname = $Voter.motherSurname
    $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO voters(curp,age,forename,middlename,surname,fatherSurname,motherSurname) VALUES('$curp','$age','$forename','$middlename','$surname','$fatherSurname','$motherSurname')"
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$conn.Close()
```

Comment: Do any of the suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/229367 help?

Comment: I don't think is Powershell related.

Comment: Have you tried to print the values read from the file to the console? Do they appear correctly?

Comment: Seems doesn't show ok to console: `Campo L�pez` should be `Campo López`

Comment: I did that, same result: `$Voters = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\Users\Derecha\Desktop\table.csv" -Encoding utf8`

Comment: That means that `C:\Users\Derecha\Desktop\table.csv` _isn't actually UTF-8_ - you need to determine the actual encoding and match that with `-Encoding`; e.g., try `-Encoding Default`  in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Your entire approach seems a bit silly, you can `INSERT INTO SomeTable SELECT Something FROM [text;HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=65001;Database=C:\SomeFolder].[SomeFile#csv]` from Powershell and not have to deal with preserving encoding from CSV to Powershell to Access (just CSV -> Access which you already figured out).

Comment: Not silly at all, the CSV file is big, if I do your way Access complains and doesn't work.

Comment: Well.. Then ask about it, because it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code correctly requests *session-wide* use of UTF-8 encoding** with this statement:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

<sup>See the documentation for the dictionary of *parameter presets* implemented via preference variable [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables?view=powershell-7#psdefaultparametervalues).</sup>

Therefore, in your case `-Encoding UTF8` is *implicitly* in effect in calls to any cmdlets that have an `-Encoding` parameter, such as `Import-Csv`.

Therefore:

- Your `Import-Csv` call *does* read your CSV file as UTF-8.
- However, your symptom (values not printing correctly in the console) suggests that **your CSV input file isn't actually UTF-8-encoded**.

Thus, the solution is to **determine the CSV file's actual encoding**<sup>[1]</sup> and **pass its name to the

`-Encoding` parameter**:

Given that, as you've since confirmed, **your file's actual encoding was ANSI** (the fixed single-byte encoding determined by your system's active legacy code page), **use the `Default` encoding name in *Windows PowerShell***:

```
$voters = Import-Csv -Encoding Default -Delimiter ',' -Path C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\mexico.csv
```

**In *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, you actually need to pass the *specific* ANSI code pag**e used, which on US-English systems is `Windows-1252`, for instance (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers) for the list of supported code pages; use either the value from the ".NET Name" column or the number from the "Identifier" column, but without a leading `0`).

```
# Use the Windows-1252 ANSI encoding.
$voters = Import-Csv -Encoding 1252 -Delimiter ',' -Path C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\mexico.csv
```

Note: As of v7.0, support for the `Default` encoding name to refer to the active ANSI code page has inexplicably not been implemented - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6562); make your voice heard there, if you'd like to see that changed.

For a **comprehensive overview of encoding behavior in PowerShell** and how it has changed between Windows PowerShell (versions up to v5.1) and PowerShell [Core] (versions starting with v6), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

---

[1] **Determining a text file's encoding:**

Note: In PowerShell [Core] 6+, `Get-Content` printing a file's text correctly *to the screen* means that *all* cmdlets will interpret it correctly; sadly, due the wildly inconsistent behavior of cmdlets in *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1) that isn't necessarily true there; `Import-Csv` is a prime example, because it defaults to ASCII(!) encoding - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for background information.

- **Platform-specific** options:

  - **Windows**:

    - Load the file into **Notepad**, which in the absence of a Unicode BOM (signature) **tries to *auto-detect* the encoding**, and can usually tell the difference between UTF-8 and ANSI: see if the text is displayed correctly, then look in the bottom right corner (status bar) for the encoding name being displayed, e.g., "ANSI"; note, however, that it won't be able to tell you what *specific ANSI code page* may have been used (if the file came from a different culture), because that is generally impossible to infer.
  - **Unix-like platforms** (macOS, Linux, including WSL):

    - Use the **`file` utility** (e.g., `file mexico.csv`) which tries to auto-detect the encoding.
    - **Caveat**: `file` misidentifies Windows-1252 as ISO-8859, which is not strictly correct - they overlap to a great degree, but aren't identical: see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
- **Cross-platform** options:

  - Pass your file to **`Format-Hex`** (e.g, `Format-Hex mexico.csv`) to **examine the byte values**; note: **be sure to pass the file to the (implied) `-Path` parameter as an *argument*** rather than piping its content via `Get-Content` to `Format-Hex`, because in the latter case `Get-Content` may already have misinterpreted the file.
  - Use **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**: while it doesn't try to auto-detect the encoding, it **offers a convenient way to re-read the file with different encodings**: Click on the name of the encoding near the bottom right corner (status bar; e.g., "UTF-8") and select `Reopen with Encoding`, then pick an encoding of interest; rinse and repeat, until the text displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a bare-minimum example without DB connectivity as I don't have MS Access. Can you can specify the `-Encoding` parameter to `Import-Csv` on your computer and see if it works?

Omitting this parameter renders gibberish on my screen.

> C??mo est??s

Specifying it explicitly to UTF8 renders this.

> Cómo estás

```
$lines = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "words.csv" -Encoding utf8

foreach ($line in $lines)
{
    $word = $line
    $query = "INSERT INTO voters(word) VALUES('$line')"
    Write-Host $query
}
```

words.csv

```
Cómo estás
Dónde estás
quién eres tú
cuando estás llegando
```

Comment: Check the .csv itself. Open it in a UTF-8 compatible text editor like Sublime Text. The file has to be encoded into UTF-8 format too.

Comment: The problem, I think is the file, was ANSI, with UTF-8 show ok: `Cómo estás`

Comment: Note that @bsteo's `Import-Csv` call in the question _implicitly_ uses `-Encoding Utf8`, thanks to `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`, so this can't be the solution, and indeed isn't, as bsteo has since confirmed. Since there is no functional difference between the code in the question and yours, this answer will confuse future readers.