# Why a binary file copied from powershell using git is different from original file?

Tags: git, powershell, command, show, git-bash

Powershell Code

```
Set-Location 'C:\Users\jdyun\Desktop\fsef'  #Test git repository
git show 18ba8db7d3ddf07a432d5e5ea141a2b779d33eb6:BugTrap.dll > CopiedBugTrap.dll
```

[Copy from Powershell git command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOfjx.png)

Using Bash

[Copy from Git-Bash git command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tpm8.png)

Copied binary file with git-bash is same binary file size

but, using powershell it is different file size between original and copied

I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: thx iRon!. I set default output encoing to utf-8. but it is also different file size.. TT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"piping" and "redirecting output" in Powershell is a bit of a mess, and doesn't work as in bash (some would simply say : doesn't work).

You can read the answer to the question suggested by @iRon :

[Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Depending on your settings :

- if the file does not begin with a `BOM`, powershell may try to convert the bytes in the input stream as if they were ASCII text, to a target encoding,
- if you don't tweak your powershell settings, the target encoding defaults to `UTF16`,
- even when you set the default output encoding to `UTF8`, I was never able to get rid of the `BOM` that it would so helpfully insert at the beginning of the output,
- etc ...

---

Bottom line is :

- if you want to "extract a file" using `git show commit:file > content`, stick to bash.
- another way to have both versions, of course, is to rename the current version of the file, and run `git checkout commit -- file`.

---

Quoting the other answer : there seems to be a "Powershell Core" edition which should fix most of these problems ; I wasn't fortunate enough to have this version at hand when I was working with Windows ;)

Comment: thx for asnwering this question. Is there any way to use the powershell to start-gitbash with parameters? like 'Start-Process git-bash.exe git show <revision>:file > new_file'

Comment: It's bash : `bash script.sh args...`, `bash -c "command"` ...