# Windows PowerShell inserts blank line after each line of output

Tags: powershell

I'm using Windows 10 and PowerShell version `5.1.19041.3930` to see the output of `qmake -project -o -` (with `qmake` being the [build management tool of Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-overview.html)), which correctly prints:

```
PS D:\vscode_test> qmake -project -o -
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Wed Jan 17 12:10:16 2024
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = unknown
INCLUDEPATH += .
[...]
```

However, when using `Out-String` to collect the result of qmake into a single string, then I suddenly get an unwanted blank line after each output line:

```
PS D:\vscode_test> qmake -project -o - | Out-String
######################################################################

# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Wed Jan 17 12:12:40 2024

######################################################################



TEMPLATE = app

TARGET = unknown

INCLUDEPATH += .

[...]
```

**Note 1:** If I just simply execute the command in a subshell with `(qmake -project -o -)`, then I **also** get the additional blank lines.

**Note 2:** If I pipe the output of a different program (e.g. `ipconfig` instead of `qmake`) into `Out-String` then I do **not** get the additional blank lines.

How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Darin Not sure, since I'm on PowerShell 5.1, but `-NoNewline` was only added in PowerShell 6.0. However, I think this would only prevent the additional newline inserted at the **very end** of the text. In no case should `Out-String` insert a newline after **each** line of the text.

Comment: `$(qmake -project -o -) -ne '' -join [environment]::NewLine` perhaps?

Comment: @Darin The `$Output` also contains the additional blank lines when printed. `$Output.GetType()` prints `Name: Object[], BaseType: System.Array`

Comment: @Theo Thank you, this works. (But will also remove blank lines already contained within the original input text.)

Comment: qmake may output utf16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Temporarily set [`[Console]::OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.OutputEncoding) to [`[Text.Encoding]::Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)**, to ensure that PowerShell decodes `qmake.exe`'s UTF-16LE-encoded output as such.

```bash
$prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding; [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode
try {
  qmake -project -o - | Out-String
}
finally {
  [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
}
```

Note:

- The use of [`try ... finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) isn't strictly necessary here, because by default external-program invocations do *not* cause trappable errors in PowerShell; however, in PowerShell 7.4+, they can, namely via the  combination of setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and `$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true` (and also - accidentally, due to historical bugs - in *Windows PowerShell* with `2>` redirections and actual stderr output).

---

##### Background information:

The likeliest explanation is that **`qmake.exe` unexpectedly emits [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE-encoded text to stdout** instead of honoring the *console's active [code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)* (as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` and reported by `chcp.com`), which defaults to the system's *legacy OEM code page*, such as [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems.

- When PowerShell *isn't* capturing `qmake.exe`'s stdout output, it prints directly to the console, presumable using the Unicode version of the [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) WinAPI function, which means that everything *prints* correctly.
- When it *does* capture `qmake.exe`'s stdout output - such as by assigning output to a variable or sending it through the pipeline - the problem arises:

  - Because PowerShell decodes the output using `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which defaults to the system's active *single-byte* OEM encoding, it *mis-decodes* the UTF-16LE output, with each `0x0` byte that forms the second part of a two-byte UTF-16LE code unit in the 8-bit subrange of Unicode (in effect, all characters that form ISO-8859-1, which includes the 7-bit ASCII subrange) becoming *a character in its own right*, with the `0x0` *bytes* becoming NULL *characters*, [`U+0000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0) (expressed as a PowerShell [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters): `` "`0" ``).
  - The *visible* manifestation of this mis-decoding is an effective doubling of newline sequences, but there are also **invisible intra-line NULL characters**, which you can visualize as follows:

    ```bash
    (qmake -project -o -) -replace '\0', '<NUL>'
    ```
  - The **effective doubling of newlines** happens as follows:

    - When an external program's stdout output is captured, PowerShell parses it *line by line* and streams each line (as it becomes available) to its success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
    - The UTF-16LE encoding of a CRLF newline sequence (composed of CARRIAGE RETURN, [`U+000D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d), i.e. code point `0xD`, and LINE FEED, [`U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a)), i.e. code point `0xA`)) is `0xD 0x0 0xA 0x0`, and - due to the mis-decoding - PowerShell sees a CR character, followed by a NULL character, [`U+0000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0)), followed by a LF character and another NULL.
    - Because PowerShell accepts CR-only, LF-only, and CRLF newline sequences *interchangeably*, the CR and LF characters *each* are interpreted as a newline (due to the interspersed NULL character, there is no longer a CRLF *sequence*).
      This means that each stdout line becomes *two* (newline-stripped) lines: the original one (with a NULL after each intra-line character), and an extra one with just a NULL character.
    - When [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) then (re)joins the streamed lines to form a single, multiline string, it uses the platform native newline sequences, i.e CRLF newlines.

      - As an aside: Perhaps surprisingly, `Out-String` adds an *extra trailing newline* to the output string. This problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).
        (Note that the PowerShell (Core) v6+-only `-NoNewLine` switch does *not* help, because it doesn't just prevent a *trailing* newline, but also newlines *between* the input strings (objects).)
      - To avoid the extra newline, use the following instead:

        ```bash
        (qmake -project -o -) -join [Environment]::NewLine
        ```
- To control the character encoding PowerShell uses when sending data *to* external programs via the pipeline (i.e. as seen by the programs via their *stdin* stream), set the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding).

  - Curiously, it defaults to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell* vs. UTF-8 in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer is helpful, @emkey08, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found a workaround for this issue by simply replacing two consecutive line breaks with a single line break only:

```
(qmake -project -o - | Out-String) -replace "`r`n`r`n", "`r`n"
```

Alternatively, as [suggested by Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77832105/77832585#comment137213732_77832105), if empty lines within the original input text don't need to be preserved, then it's also simply possible to just remove them altogher:

```
(qmake -project -o -) -ne '' | Out-String
```