# How can I format my string to be recognized as a path in my PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

The point of this odd little script is just to let me choose a directory and have whatever is in my clipboard written to a text file in that path. This path will unfortunately always contain parentheses, brackets, and sometimes braces.

```
Y:

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="")

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$myFolder = Get-Folder('Y:\MyStuff (OtherStuff)')

Get-Clipboard > $myFolder\myFile.txt
```

Because of the brackets in the subfolder, I get this error message

```
out-file : Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path Y:\MyStuff
(OtherStuff)\Sub1\Sub2 [Info] [Some More Info]\myFile.txt did not resolve to a file.
At line:22 char:1
+ Get-Clipboard > $myFolder\myFile.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Y:\Music (MyStu...nfo]\myFile.txt:Stri 
   ng) [Out-File], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutF 
   ileCommand
```

No amount of -replace combinations to account for the escape characters using ' or \ has resulted in success. How can I format the string so it resolves to a real directory?

**Second question**
Is there a way to select a path with the more user-friendly FileBrowserDialog instead of FolderBrowser where you can't type or paste in a path?

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell, functions are invoked _like shell commands_ - `Get-Folder  Y:\MyStuff (OtherStuff)'` - _not_ like C# methods - `Get-Folder('Y:\MyStuff (OtherStuff)')`; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a function sees as a _single_ argument.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use `Set-StrictMode -Version 2 or higher, but note that this places additional constraints on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, `> $myFolder\myFile.txt` is the equivalent of
`| Out-File -FilePath $myFolder\myFile.txt`, and the `-FilePath` parameter<sup>[1]</sup> interprets its argument as a  [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), in which `[` and `]` have special meaning.

The workaround is to use the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet - or with *text* input, the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet - with the `-LiteralPath` parameter, which uses its argument(s) *literally* (verbatim):

```
Get-Clipboard | Out-File -LiteralPath $myFolder\myFile.txt
```

Note: In Windows PowerShell, `Out-File` and `Set-Content` use different default character encodings; in PowerShell [Core] v6+, BOM-less UTF-8 is consistently used - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

To specify the desired encoding explicitly, use the `-Encoding` parameter.

---

<sup>[1] Note: In other cmdlets the equivalent parameter is named just `-Path`; in PowerShell [Core] v6+, this inconsistency was corrected, and `Out-File` there supports both `-FilePath` and `-Path` interchangeably.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This function may answer question 2. It will even let you choose a directory inside a zip folder. Optional InitialDirectory and message.

```
function Get-Folder {
    Param(
        $initialDirectory = 17,
        $message = "Choose a directory"
    )

    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $selection = $shell.browseforfolder(0,$message,65556,$initialDirectory)
    if($selection){$selection.self.path}
}

get-folder 'c:\some\pa(th)'
```

Comment: Nice; the method is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-browseforfolder), and the constants for the initial dir. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants).

Comment: Thanks. I also found these useful [1](http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch12f.html) [2](http://www.lee-mac.com/directorydialog.html) [3](https://ss64.com/vb/browseforfolder.html)