# Formatting a text file with columns in powershell

Tags: powershell, object, output, text-files, hashtable

I am trying to create an nicely formatted Txt file (has to be Txt cannot be CSV) from a hashtable.

Here is the code that I have that creates the text file

```
$hashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name |
ForEach-Object {"{0} `t`t: {1} `t`t: {2} `t`t: {3} `t`t: {4}" -f $_.DisplayName,$_.EmployeeNo,$_.Email, $_.SamName,$_.Upn}|
Add-Content $textFilePath
```

As you can see - when someone is input into the Txt file with a long name it messes up the formatting because the tabs just get shifted along.
[image]

I'm looking for a solution that dynamically sets the width of the columns in a text file.

Comment: As an aside: I assume it's just a posting artifact, but your code doesn't work as-is, because what is seen as `$_` in the pipeline isn't an AD user object directly, it is a `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` instance whose `.Value` property contains the AD user object. In other word, instead of `$_.DisplayName` it would have to be `$_.Value.DisplayName`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PowerShell's output-formatting system, whose [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) cmdlet produces human-readable, column-aligned representations, but note that these are generally *not* suitable for later *programmatic* processing:

```
($hashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name).Value | 
  Format-Table -AutoSize -Property DisplayName, EmployeeNo, Email, SamName, Upn | 
    Out-File $textFilePath -Encoding Utf8 -Width 1024
```

- `$hashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name` enumerates the hashtable entries as `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` entries and sorts them by their `.Name` (`.Key`) property.

  - Note that the `.GetEnumerator()` call is necessary to sort the hash table *entries* by their key (name); without it, the hash table *as a whole* would be sent *as a single object* through the pipeline, in which case the `Sort-Object` would effectively be a *no-op* - by definition, there's nothing to sort if there's only one object; compare the output from:
    `@{ zach = 1; moe = 2; aardvark = 0 } | Sort-Object Name`
    to the output from:
    `@{ zach = 1; moe = 2; aardvark = 0 }.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name`
    In the first command, the `Sort-Object` call has no effect.
- `.Value` then extracts the entries' values (this could also be done in streaming fashion with `... | ForEach-Object Value`).
- The values appears to be Active Directory user objects, so you can just pass a list of the desired property *names* to `Format-Table`, which form the output-table column names, whereas the corresponding property *values* form the column values.
- Note that `Out-File` rather than `Add-Content` (`Set-Content`) is used, because only it automatically converts the formatting *objects* that `Format-Table` outputs to their intended string representations, as you would see in the console (terminal).

  - `-Width 1024` ensures that the table lines aren't truncated based on whatever the width of the current console window happens to be; adjust as needed.
  - `-Encoding Utf8` is used as an example to control the output encoding; note that *Windows PowerShell* defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE), whereas the default is BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for more information about default character encodings in Windows PowerShell vs. PowerShell [Core].

Comment: Does `Format-Table` have a `-Width` parameter? I think maybe that goes with `Out-File`.  Checked documentation and tested in 5.1 and 7.0.  I'm also not sure we need `.GetEnumerator()` , in this scenario `$hashTable.Values | Sort-Object Name | ...` seems to work just as well.  Is there a reason to specify the encoding?

Comment: Yes - thank you @Steven: the `-Width` belongs with the `Out-File` command - fixed. As for your other points: please see my update.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake. In my test data I included a name property. So sorting on the underlying object’s name property rather than the key of the hash. Thanks!

Comment: I understand.  In my erroneous experiment I didn't send the hash table in whole down the pipeline. I sent the `.Values` property of the hash table.  Should the objects stored in the hash have a name property, like an  AD users, PwSh would sort on it.  Of course, that's not the same as sorting on the key. My error was in creating test data that indeed had a name property when in fact I didn't know what the key was.  And, the rest followed.

Comment: Got it, @Steven. What probably added to the confusion is that the code in the question doesn't work as-is, because instead of `$_.DisplayName` it would have to be `$_.Value.DisplayName`, and so on.