# Powershell scipt for replacing a line in every file in directory doesn't work

Tags: powershell, shell, replace, directory, find

I wanted to make a powershell script to make altering a line in multiple files go faster.

It's really the first time I'm trying to make something like this.
What I basically want to do :

1. Select all the files in a directory that have a ".xml" extension
2. Go through every line per file and check if the it contains de following text (example: `<package>true</package>`) /
3. Then I want to change the above example text to the new text (example: `<package>false</package>`)
   Also if the file doesn't contain `<package>true</package>` I also want to add `<package>false</package>`
4. After that it should just save the file not create a new one somewhere else.

I've never really used powershell before so I did some digging and came up with this code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem –Path 'C:\test-XML\XML' -Recurse -Filter *.xml 
$tempFilePath = 'C:\test-XML\newXml'
$find = '<packag>true</package>'
$replace = '<packag>false</package>'


foreach ($f in $files){
   (Get-Content $f) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
}
```

With this code I should be able to get all the files in the directory and then loop trough it and change the text with the newer text. But it doesn't work and it also doesn't cover all the points I needed to make the task easier.

Does anyone have insights to make it work and or even make it better than it is now.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job. Instead of RegEx, use XML parser. `$xml = [xml]( Get-Content $f -raw )`. Now you have an instance of [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0) which you can use to check for elements and modify their contents in a more robust way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's worth heeding [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42)'s advice: For processing XML files, it is more robust to use a dedicated XML parser, notably `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)).

If plain-text processing is an option - and it sounds like it is for you - you can use the following approach, which updates all files *in place*; it is optimized for performance:

```
Get-ChildItem –LiteralPath C:\test-XML\XML -Recurse -Filter *.xml |
  ForEach-Object {
    # CAUTION: This updates files *in place*.
    #          Adjust the encoding as needed.
    Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $_.FullName -Value (
      (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) -replace '<package>true</package>', '<package>false</package>'
    )
  }
```

Note:

- The primary problem with your code was presumably just a typo: `<packag>` -> `<package>`.
- The file content is updated *in place*, so it's best to back up the files first, to be safe. There's a hypothetical risk of file corruption if the process of writing back the updated content gets interrupted.
- For efficiency, [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw` reads the entire file into a single, multi-line string (the default behavior is to output an *array* of *lines*, which is much slower), so that only a single [`-replace` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) is needed. If nothing matches in the input string, it is returned as-is.
- Note that PowerShell always uses a file-writing cmdlet's *default* character encoding on output, irrespective of the encoding that the input file uses, hence the explicit use of [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s
  `-Encoding` parameter.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for more information about default encodings in Windows PowerShell vs. PowerShell [Core] v6+.
- Note that the updated content is passed to `Set-Content` `-Value` parameter rather than via the pipeline (`$content | Set-Content ...`); while it makes little difference in performance here, given that only *one* string is passed, with array-of-lines processing it would: if, say, `$content` contains the array of lines to write to file, `Set-Content ... -Value $content` will be much faster than `$content | Set-Content ...`
- For brevity, the `Set-Content` and `Get-Content` call pass the filename argument *positionally*, which implicitly binds to the `-Path` parameter, which, strictly speaking, accepts [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards); typically, that works as expected even if you pass a *literal* filename, but the more robust approach is to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter, as shown in the `Get-ChildItem` call above; specifically, literal filenames that contain `[` and `]` result in misinterpretation by the `-Path` parameter, except if they're *escaped* .