# Issues with specific characters in outfile

Tags: powershell, merge, file-io, formatting

I have a script that merges files and that works fine - but characters like åäö looks not good in the output file

Here is the complete script:

```
$startOfToday = (Get-Date).Date
Get-ChildItem "C:\TEST -include *.* -Recurse |
Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt $startOfToday | ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} | 
Out-File "C:\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/mm/dd').txt"
```

In the files in looks like this for example

```
Order ID 1

Order ID 2

This is för får
```

In the output it gets like this for the last row

```
Order ID 1

Order ID 2

fÃ¥r fÃ¶r fÃ¤r
```

is there a way to make those characters appear in the output file as they appear in the first file?

Comment: Try `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`. `Out-File` defaults to UTF16LE encoding. My thoughts are if `Get-Content` reads the data as intended then `Set-Content` should be just as intelligent? I could be wrong.

Comment: How are the source files encoded? If you remove the `| Out-File ...` part of the pipeline, does `ö` and `å` render correctly in your terminal?

Comment: Set-Content did it! Thanks

Comment: @AdminOfThings, `Set-Content` is effective _in this specific scenario_, because it applies the same misinterpretation that `Get-Content` applies on reading also on writing, pass-through style, but it's important to note that _in memory_ the strings will be incorrectly represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication is that **your input files are UTF-8-encoded *without a BOM*, which in *Windows PowerShell* are (mis)interpreted to be ANSI-encoded** (using the system's active ANSI code page, such as Windows-1252).

The solution is to **tell `gc` ([`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) explicitly what encoding to use, via the `-Encoding` parameter**:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TEST -include *.* -Recurse |
  Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt $startOfToday | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 $_; ""} | 
      Out-File "C:\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/mm/dd').txt"
```

Note that PowerShell never preserves the input encoding automatically, therefore, in the absence of using `-Encoding` with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), its default encoding is used, which is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) in *Windows PowerShell*.

While ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*** also doesn't preserve input encodings, it **consistently defaults to BOM-less UTF-8**, so your original code would work as-is there.

For more information about default encodings in Windows PowerShell vs. PowerShell (Core) 7+, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

---

Note: As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) suggests in a comment, simply replacing `Out-File` with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) in your original code also works *in this particular case*, because the *same misinterpretation* of the encoding is then performed on both in- and output, and the data is simply being *passed through*. This isn't a *general* solution, however, notably not if you need to process the strings in memory first, before saving them to a file.