# Github actions: set environment variable for Windows build with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, github-actions

I define `GENERATOR_PLATFORM` as an empty environment variable, and then I want
to set it to something for my Windows build.  But, the variable never gets set:

```
env:
  GENERATOR_PLATFORM:

 steps:
    - name: windows-dependencies
      if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'windows')
      run: |
         $generator= "-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64"
        echo "Generator: ${generator}"
        echo "GENERATOR_PLATFORM=$generator" >> $GITHUB_ENV

   - name: Configure CMake
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      run: cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE $GENERATOR_PLATFORM
```

Comment: An important thing to note for anyone coming here because they can't get an environment variable to set in PowerShell: If you set the variable and then get it in the same step, it will not work. [Apparently,](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25713#discussioncomment-3248870) the GITHUB_ENV file isn't updated in the same step.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using a Windows/PowerShell environment, you have to use `$env:GITHUB_ENV` instead of `$GITHUB_ENV`:

```
    echo "GENERATOR_PLATFORM=$generator" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
```

This way, you can access your env var through `$env:GENERATOR_PLATFORM`, eg:

```
    run: echo $env:GENERATOR_PLATFORM
```

Comment: You might take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700484/github-action-windows-assign-variable-to-github-env

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on @soltex answer: The proposed solution only works if the encoding is set to utf-8. If your runner is using Windows PowerShell (i.e. not PowerShell v7+, which uses utf-8 by default), utf16-le is written to the environment file, which causes the variable to not being set.

The correct solution is this:

```
echo "GENERATOR_PLATFORM=$generator" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

From: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/5251#issuecomment-1071030822

Further reading: [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: You might take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700484/github-action-windows-assign-variable-to-github-env