# Outputs for Github Actions on Windows hosted runner

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I want to access step outcome from previous job on my Windows self-hosted runner. In order to do so, I use output variables like below, which works just fine (printing "success" in the last step).

```yaml
name: Debug workflow

on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: tester-1
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.MY_OUTPUT }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout with submodules
        id: checkout_step
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Write variable to output
        id: step1
        run: echo '::set-output name=MY_OUTPUT::${{ steps.checkout_step.outcome }}'
  job2:
    runs-on: tester-1
    needs: job1
    env:
      OUTPUT1: '${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}'
    steps:
    - name: Print outputs from previous 
      run: echo ${{ env.OUTPUT1 }}
```

However `::set-output` [is deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) so I would like to convert to correct approach. Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733076/github-actions-set-environment-variable-for-windows-build-with-powershell), I've already tried replacing my `echo '::set-output name=MY_OUTPUT::${{ steps.checkout_step.outcome }}'` to

1. `echo "MY_OUTPUT=${{ steps.checkout_step.outcome }}" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV`
2. `echo "MY_OUTPUT=${{ steps.checkout_step.outcome }}" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf8 -Append`

Using either version results in an error from printing step and empty `OUTPUT1` variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
Run echo 
  echo 
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    OUTPUT1: 
Write-Output : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: InputObject.
At C:\tester-1-runner\_work\_temp\a19d4f45-cf0e-4ddb-b62e-4f05a2f00461.ps1:2 char:1
+ echo
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Output], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteOutputCommand
 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up outputs and environment variables.

The proper syntax for populating env vars with `shell: bash` is:

```bash
echo "foo=bar" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

and for outputs:

```bash
echo "foo=bar" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

As you're using a Windows runner, your solution should be with `$ENV:GITHUB_OUTPUT`:

```yaml
run: echo "MY_OUTPUT=${{ steps.checkout_step.outcome }}" >> $ENV:GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

After that, the `echo` should work fine:

```bash
echo ${{ env.OUTPUT1 }}
```

or,

```bash
echo $ENV:OUTPUT1
```

See these threads for more details:

- [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)
- [Value not set using $GITHUB_OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443940/value-not-set-using-github-output)