# How to set or change a global variable in github action?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I have a github action:

```
name: Test

on:
 workflow_dispatch:

env:
  PREX: false
  

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
   
    - name: Say Hi
      run: |
        # Print the PREX environment variable
        echo "${{ env.PREX }}"

    - name: Say Hi2  
      if: contains(steps.get-version.outputs.version-suffix, 'beta')
      run: |
        echo "PREX=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Say Hi3
      run: |
        # Print the PREX environment variable
        echo "${{ env.PREX }}"
```

I want to change Prex variable value to true if my condition is true. But everytime i check it value is false. I expect a true value when i print it in Hi3 section, becasue i changed its value in Hi2 section. I can confirm that my if condition works fine (i can use exit 1 command and workflow will be canceled so if statement works fine but Prex value does not set/change)
I removed other codes for simple code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github actions: set environment variable for Windows build with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733076/github-actions-set-environment-variable-for-windows-build-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Powershell on Windows. You need to use `$env:GITHUB_ENV` to reference it, or set `shell: bash` instead.

```yaml
      run: |
        echo "PREX=true" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
```

or

```yaml
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "PREX=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

or

```yaml
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Comment: Tnx in current job i can see that my variable changed, now i added another job, but here i see old value and updated value does not shown. I am use like this in job2 ${{ env.PREX }}

Comment: @PowerCode You need to use [job outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) to preserve the value across multiple jobs.