# How to show Gradle build info using UTF-8 correctly in Powershell

Tags: powershell, gradle, githooks

Currently I changed my PowerShell to use code page 65001(aka UTF-8).

I have researched some questions on StackOverFlow, and changed my project *gradle.properties* and add the following properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

But when starting Powershell, and execute Gradle build. And then execute Git commit/push, it includes a [Kotlinter Git hook](https://github.com/jeremymailen/kotlinter-gradle#git-hooks).

[image]

The standalone build task is ok, but the Git hook command that calls Gradle tasks and shows console info like the image.

Comment: does this help: [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40098771/995714)?