# Spliting value of new-item and store in text file

Tags: powershell

beginner in powershell and trying to get better.

I am creating a text file in powershell with 3 lines

```
new-item -itemtype file -Value "1,2,3"  modules.txt
```

However the output of it is "1,2,3" instead of a new line for each item

1

2

3

I tried `new-item -itemtype file -Value "1,2,3" -split ","  modules.txt`

But could not use that parameter inline since it would not be recognized.
Also tried saving it to an array.

```
$array = '1,2,3' -split ','
```

However when running

```
new-item -itemtype file -Value "$array"  modules.txt
```

It would all still appear in one line

Grateful for any advice

Answer (score 3):

**[`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) doesn't meaningfully support an *array* of values** to write to the new file, neither via an argument passed to its `-Value` parameter nor via the pipeline.

You have two options:

- Either: **Create a multi-line representation of your array yourself**, with each (stringified) element on its own line, using the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator:

  ```bash
  # Note: + [Environment]::NewLine adds a *trailing* newline,
  #       which may or may not be necessary. 
  New-Item modules.txt -Value (
    1, 2, 3 -join [Environment]::NewLine + [Environment]::NewLine
  )
  ```

  - As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, a simpler alternative is to use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), which *automatically* appends a trailing newline to its output string,<sup>[1]</sup> and stringifies complex objects using PowerShell's rich output formatting system, not by calling the `.ToString()` method on each element the way `-join` implicitly does (for strings and primitive types such as numbers, this won't make a difference):

    ```bash
    New-Item modules.txt -Value (1, 2, 3 | Out-String)

    # Ditto, via the pipeline. This is possible, because
    # Out-String creates a *single* object, namely a multi-line string.
    1, 2, 3 | Out-String | New-Item modules.txt
    ```
- Or: **Use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) instead**, which *implicitly* creates the file (see caveat below); its `-Value` parameter / pipeline input processing *does* handle arrays properly:

  ```bash
  Set-Content modules.txt -Value 1, 2, 3

  # Ditto, via the pipeline (slower)
  1, 2, 3 | Set-Content modules.txt
  ```

**Caveats**:

- As a safety measure, `New-Item` refuses to create the target file if a file by that name already exists - you can use `-Force` to override that.
- By contrast, `Set-Content` *quietly overwrites* a preexisting file, so you'd have to test for the existence of the target file first to prevent accidental overwriting.
- Character encoding:

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, where different cmdlets unfortunately use different default encodings (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/453750)), `New-Item` creates BOM-less UTF-8 files by default, whereas `Set-Content` defaults to ANSI encoding.
  - Fortunately, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, BOM-less UTF-8 is now used *consistently* as the default, across all cmdlets.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `... -Value "1,2,3" ...`

Passing [*string literal*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) `"1,2,3"` predictably writes that string *as-is* to the target file (as verbatim value `1,2,3`).

> `... -Value "$array" ...`

By enclosing (a variable containing) an array in `"..."`, you implicitly *stringify* it, resulting in a single string that joins the (stringified) array elements with a *space* as the separator,<sup>[2]</sup> resulting in verbatim `1 2 3`. You can verify this with `"$(1, 2, 3)"`.

---

<sup>[1] While helpful in this particular use case, this behavior is problematic in general - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).</sup>

<sup>[2] Space is the *default* separator character. Technically, you can override it via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), though that is rarely used in practice.</sup>

Comment: 'mklement0', has given you a solid answer. However, Point of Note: If you are going to use arrays, the best practice is to use real arrays. Especially if you have complete control over the process. See these details. [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Hey @mklement0 thanks for that, i've learn a lot from your answer!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @itnoob; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this here, since it is too long for a normal comment.

***Ditto to 'mklement0' helpful answer***.

Yet, there are always different ways to deal with one thing or the other, and the choice is yours.

If you want an array, why not just start with one? ***@(1,2,3)***  Right now you are using a single string and splitting it.

Again, 'mklement0', is the most direct, but, here is what I mean, because you say, you are creating the file, not that you are reading a file you are given, thus you have complete control of this creation effort:

***(again, just giving you food for thought):***

```
# Create a new array, assigning the results to a variable and output to screen
($array = @(1,2,3))

# Or as a string set
($array = @('1','2','3'))
# Results using either of the above, no extra splittng required
<#
1
2
3
#>

$array.Count
# Results
<#
3
#>

# Create a text file of the results
# Remove existing file, if it exists
Remove-Item -Path 'modules.txt' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$array |
ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Path 'modules.txt' -Value $PSitem}
Get-Content -Path 'modules.txt'
# Results
<#
1
2
3
#>

# Or using what you have
# Remove existing file, if it exists
Remove-Item -Path 'modules.txt' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
'1,2,3' -split ',' |
ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Path 'modules.txt' -Value $PSitem}
Get-Content -Path 'modules.txt'
# Results
<#
1
2
3
#>

# Here is another way, using what you show, using string -replace vs string split
# Remove existing file, if it exists
Remove-Item -Path 'modules.txt' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
($array = ('1,2,3')) -replace ',',"`r`n" | 
Out-File -FilePath 'modules.txt'
Get-Content -Path 'modules.txt'
# Results
<#
1
2
3
#>

# Remove existing file, if it exists
Remove-Item -Path 'modules.txt' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$array = '1,2,3' -replace ',',"`r`n" | 
Out-File -FilePath 'modules.txt'
Get-Content -Path 'modules.txt'
# Results
<#
1
2
3
#>
```

Comment: Good point about starting with an array - I did so implicitly in my answer, but it's worth calling out explicitly.

Comment: hey @postanote thank you so much for your insight! i had a read with the array that we create using `($array = @(1,2,3))`
however i can't seem to use it in new-item since it doesn't meaningfully support an array of values where it would just write "System.Object[ ]", to overcome that i can use set-content which supports arrays however what difference would it make as compared to `Set-Content modules.txt -Value 1, 2, 3` w/o having to create a array first?

Comment: No worries, but again, look at 'mklement0 ', the direct option, and pay close attention to the array use he and I are showing. If you don't enumerate, you will only get a singular response. Arrays are SystemObjects by design, hence the enum. Don't get wrapped around barn messing with New-Item. As he and I are showing, you have options. Why are you driving so hard with New-Item?