# adb logcat > file.log encoding

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I use `adb logcat > file.log` in window and then open file.log in vscode.

It shows that the encoding of file is UTF-8. But the chinese is messy code.

In Android Studio Logcat and powershell7 terminal, the logcat show chinese correctly. But After redirect the log to file, chinese is shown  as messy code.

[image]

What should I do to get correct log file with chinese?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/150978) about how to change encoding in powershell for files could be helpful.

Comment: @Robert nooo, my powershell 7 terminal is utf-8 encoding, but it still messy code.  Whatever, Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 have a new style logcat, which can meet my need.