# configuring ssl for localhost

Tags: apache, ssl, localhost, configure

So I am creating some simple html pages for a school project using Apache, localhost, on windows10.
I generated the key and csr and am trying to configure it to localhost by using cnf file called extfile.cnf
the file reads "subjectAltName=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1"

The command I am using in windows powershell is  'C:\ssl> openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in cert.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf -CAcreateserial'

I am following an instructional video and everything has been fine until this point and im getting an error that says "x509: Error on line 1 of config file "extfile.cnf""
so there is something wrong and I have tried editing the file several ways and cannot get it to work.
the video I am following is here: https://youtu.be/VH4gXcvkmOY
I am using windows powershell and have tried in administrator but same result.
The relevant part of the video starts at 12 min 40 sec.

any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

> I am using windows powershell  ...

Powershell by default outputs to UTF-16, which is not what OpenSSL expects for the input file format. A comment on the video you reference also says this:

> James Brasington
> 1 month ago
> Had to convert the file extfile.cnf from UTF-16 to UTF-8 in notpad++ but other than that worked great

A search for the error message you get also leads to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/openssl/comments/uual4e/missing_equal_sign_extfile/) with a similar error - although the OP here posted the full error message and not just a part of it. This is always recommended. The solution here also was:

> For future reference...I found the issue. The extfile.cnf needs to be encoded to UTF-8

See also [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)