# Powershell - how to read Ansi CSV file

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

Notepad++ says the CSV file is Ansi encoded.

The Powershell 7 Import-CSV commandlet has various -Encoding options but 'Ansi' is not one of them.

How do I get Powershell to read this CSV without mangling it?

The options for -Encoding are:

- ascii
- bigendianunicode
- bigendianutf32
- oem
- unicode
- utf7
- utf8
- utf8BOM
- utf8NoBOM
- utf32

Comment: Did you... try... any of them? Lower half of character mappings in `ANSI` is the same as `ASCII`, give that a try :)

Comment: If I use ASCII it mangles all the special characters/diacritics in the data. Ascii and Ansi are not the same encoding

Comment: *Did you... try... any of them?* yes I did, no need to be snarky

Comment: I didn't mean to be, I was genuinely curious - your original post contains no mention of diacritics or special characters, and no mention of what you've tried :)

Comment: Thats why encoding is complicated, people who live in ASCII-alphabet countries dont have to think about it until they hit a CSV file full of international names and addresses. Turns out Powershell is missing an Ansi option.

Comment: *no mention of what you've tried* If I'd written "I tried all the other encodings that aren't ansi and none of them were able to read an ansi file" I would have just looked even dumber

Comment: It might be utf8 if it's utf8nobom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use **ANSI encoding**, i.e. the specific code page implied by the active legacy system locale (language for non-Unicode programs), such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

- in *Windows PowerShell*:

  ```
  -Encoding Default
  ```
- in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which you're using, `Default` now refers to UTF-8, so more work is needed:

  - In PowerShell **v7.3-**:

    ```
    -Encoding ([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)
    ```
  - In PowerShell **v7.4+**:<sup>[1]</sup>

    ```
    -Encoding Ansi
    ```

---

**Default character encodings in the two PowerShell editions**:

- ***Windows PowerShell***, the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition (whose latest and *last* version is v5.1.x), **defaults to the active ANSI code page in *key* areas** - notably `Get-Content` / `Set-Content` and when the PowerShell engine reads source code - but the **defaults *vary widely* across the built-in cmdlets**; case in point: `Import-Csv` defaults to UTF-8; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for an overview.
- **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, the modern, install-on-demand, cross-platform edition (which started with v6 and is currently at v7.2.x), now fortunately **consistently defaults to *(BOM-less) UTF-8*.**

---

<sup>[1] The absence of an `Ansi` `-Encoding` value in earlier  PowerShell (Core) versions was a curious omission, given that an `Oem` value (for the active OEM code page) has always existed - see [GitHub issue #6562](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6562) for the backstory.</sup>

Comment: So the default used to be Ansi, they (sensibly) changed it to UTF-8 but then forgot they needed an Ansi option.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, @codeulike. Please see my update re default encodings in the two PowerShell editions.

Comment: Good new, @codeulike: `-Encoding Ansi` will work in the upcoming 7.4 version, which is already available in a preview version.