# How to output file in the right encoding by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, adb, logcat, file-encodings

I'm trying to output my log file to disk in PowerShell, but i get wrong file content.

Info as follow:

Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 21H2

PowerShell Version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Default Encoding:

```
Preamble          :
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Scene:

```
adb logcat WeatherActivity:D *:S > weather.log
```

[the log file outputed in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1hgT.png)

When i do the same thing in git bash or mobaxterm, it get the right content like this.

[the log file outputed in git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAhfC.png)

What i have tried:
Change PowerShell version from 5.1 to 7.3.6

The PowerShell 7 use UTF-8 to out-file by default, so it may not be this reason?

Releated work i've read:

[Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8/40098904#40098904)

I'm expecting PowerShell give the right output file.

Comment: The redirection operators map to `Out-File`, which defaults to UTF16-LE. Pipe your output to `Set-Content -Encoding utf8` instead

Comment: It is probably a different font, not encoding.

Comment: `Out-File` defalts to UTF-8 in my PowerShell 7. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Please especially share those Chinese strings (both wrong and right ones)…

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @mklement0 worked for me.

`[Console]::OutputEncoding` must match the character encoding used in adb's output. If it is UTF-8, (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`. If you make UTF-8 the default encoding system-wide, as shown in the last link in your question, that won't be necessary, but this change has far-reaching consequences. –
mklement0

By the way, it's another easy way to fix this as follow.
[image: change system area language setting]