# Keep Encoding from Docker-Container

Tags: docker, powershell, utf-8, mariadb, utf-16

I use MariaDB on Docker for Windows with the Powershell.
When I want to create a mysqldump with docker exec and redirect the file from container to hostsystem, the encoding changes from UTF8 to UTF16.

This is my command to create mysqldump:

```
docker exec -i containername mysqldump -uusername -ppassword database > .\sql-filename.sql
```

And cause of this ">" the file will be encoded in UTF16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: Thank you for the link and your help.
I tried this and without docker on a native installed MariaDB instance it works fine. 
Also it works when I use Docker and connect explicit to the container to create the sql-dump within the container like below:

1. docker exec -it containername /bin/bash
2. mysqldump -u username -p database > ./sql-filename.sql
3. docker cp containername:/sql-filename.sql C:\path\on\hostsystem

The encoding within the container is utf8 and the encoding within the database schema is utf8mb4.

Comment: I have one more finding. When i use the command docker exec -it containername mysqldump -uusername -ppassword database i get the content on the powerhsell output and there is everything fine. German umlauts for example are correct.

Comment: But german umlauts are set correctly, when I use Set-Content and the text is directy written on the console. Like this command: "Text with German umlauts: ÄäÖöÜü" | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\umlauts.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the usage of Powershell 5.1.
With the installation of Windows Terminal and Powershell (7+) via the Microsoft Store it is possible to change the encoding.
Important is to use the pwsh.exe and not powershell.exe.
After installation the following settings must be done. So the link of Pino is great.

```
#if you want to revert the default-encoding you should save the actual settings
$defaultEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
# Set the encoding to UTF8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
# docker exec command, also | Set-Content sql-file.sql is possible
docker exec -i containername mysqldump -uusername -ppassword database > .\sql-filename.sql
# revert default encoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $defaultEncoding
```