# Fix lines in tsv file to combine with next line

Tags: powershell, csv

I have an output file that experiences an issue. The file is a tsv file consisting of 1.25 million lines (660 Mil characters).  The process to create this file seems to store 100,000 characters in its buffer then dumps it to the tsv, placing a carriage return and starting a new line. The remaining data is then placed into this file on a new line, entering 100,000 characters and repeating the process above.

```
Example:
1 ......48 fields...CR LF
2 ......48 fields...CR LF
3 ......48 fields...CR LF
4 ......37 fields CR LF
5 ......11 fields CR LF
6 ......48 fields...CR LF
7 ......48 fields...CR LF
8 ......48 fields...CR LF
9 ......17 fields CR LF
10 ......21 fields CR LF
```

Lines 1-4 contain 100,000 characters including the CR LF for all lines
Lines 5-9 contain 100,000 characters including the CR LF for all lines

The tsv has a header row of 48 values, 47 delimiters. The rows that are 'broken' have less than the 47 delimiters. I have created a PowerShell that can provide me the row numbers, I could even edit the file in Notepad++, but there are over 5,000 lines that must be fixed in the file EACH DAY!  I'm looking for a method to script this. This appears to be approximately every 190 rows, but that is not a constant due to character count. I basically need a way to go 100,000 characters, remove the carriage return so the next line joins with the line to make a full 48 field line.

I can't remove all the carriage returns and line breaks because that will create a mess. Any ideas how to take the first row not matching the delimiter count and join it to the following row to fix the data row, and continue on to the next instance showing this issue and fixing it?

I have tried PowerShell replacing the current line and removing the carriage return but updating the file places the carriage return back in its place.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pre-process the file before you even try to use it as a tsv file - basically copy the first 100,000 bytes from the source file into a new file, then *skip* 2 bytes from the source file and copy the next 100,000 bytes, *skip* 2 bytes again and copy 1000,000, etc until you've re-assembled the required tsv file. This might depend on things like whether the header row is buffered as well, and the encoding scheme (UTF8, ASCII or whatever) but I don't think there's an easy way to stream the data and filter out the unwanted CRLF on-the-fly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The following performs line-by-line plain-text processing, and decides based on the count of tab chars. on each line which lines need joining in order to effectively remove the extraneous newline (CRLF).
- The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with its `-File` parameter allows for fast (by PowerShell standards) line-by-line reading.
- A [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) instance is used to write the output file.
- Character-encoding caveat:

  - `System.IO.StreamWriter` defaults to creating BOM-less UTF-8 files, though you may control the encoding explicitly, via a constructor parameter.
  - If the input file has no BOM, `switch` *invariably* assumes UTF-8 encoding.<sup>[1]</sup>

    - If you need to specify a different encoding, use a [`System.IO.StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader) instance instead.

```bash
# Specify your input file here.
$inFile = 'in.csv'
# The count of separators (tabs) on each line.
$expectedTabCount = 47 

# Create a writer for the output file (must be different from the input file).
# NOTE: Be sure to use a *full path*
$outFileWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$pwd/out.tsv"

# Initialize helper variables.
$potentiallyCompleteLine = $incompleteLine = $null

# Process the input file line by line, join the split lines as needed,
# and write to the output file.
switch -File $inFile {
  default {
    if ($incompleteLine) {
      # Previous line was incomplete.
      # Join the incomplete line with the current one and write to the file.
      $outFileWriter.WriteLine($incompleteLine + $_)
      $incompleteLine = $null
    } elseif (($_ -replace '[^\t]').Length -lt $expectedTabCount) {
      # Incomplete line
      if ($potentiallyCompleteLine -and $_ -notmatch '\t') {
        # The previous line had the expected count of separators, but was
        # cut in half in the last field.
        $outFileWriter.WriteLine($potentiallyCompleteLine + $_)
        $potentiallyCompleteLine = $null
      } else {
        if ($potentiallyCompleteLine) {
          # Write the previous potentially complete line, which can now be
          # assumed to be complete.
          $outFileWriter.WriteLine($potentiallyCompleteLine)
          $potentiallyCompleteLine = $null
        }  
        # Save the current line, which must be joined with the next one.
        $incompleteLine = $_
      }
    } else {
      # Complete line.
      if ($potentiallyCompleteLine) {
        # Write the previous potentially complete line, which can now be
        # assumed to be complete.
        $outFileWriter.WriteLine($potentiallyCompleteLine)
      }
      # This line has the expected number of separators, but the line could still
      # be incomplete if the CRLF was inserted *in the middle of the last field*,
      # so writing must be deferred.
      $potentiallyCompleteLine = $_
    }
  }
}
# Write the last complete line.
if ($potentiallyCompleteLine) { $outFileWriter.WriteLine($potentiallyCompleteLine) }
$outFileWriter.Close()
```

---

<sup>[1] Surprisingly, this also applies to the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition, which - mostly, but not consistently - defaults to the system's active *ANSI* code page (whereas the modern, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8). For the varying defaults in Windows PowerShell, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: The changes worked like a charm! Thank you for coming up with a solution for me so quick.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @SlackerSean; my pleasure.